# Golang casting a multiple return value to match named result parameter

Tags: casting, go

Let's assume I want to define a function with named result parameters, one of which is a `string`. This function internally calls another function, that returns a bytes representation of such string.

Is there a way to cast the result without using a temporary variable?

```
func main() {
    out, _ := bar("Example")
    fmt.Println(out)
}

func foo(s string) ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(s), nil
}

func bar(in string) (out string, err error) {
    // is there a way to assign the result to out
    // casting the value to string in the same line
    // istead of using the tmp variable?
    tmp, err := foo(in)

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(tmp), nil
}
```

The idea is that, if that's possible, I could potentially shorten the code to

```
func bar(in string) (out string, err error) {
    // assuming there is a way to cast out to string
    out, err := foo(in)
    return
}
```

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to cast in a multiple return from a function. That doesn't mean you can't shorten your code though. http://play.golang.org/p/bf4D71_rZF If you don't care about the error then just cast the variable in your inline return

Comment: This is one of the versions I wrote. However, this version makes named parameters worthless. Do you agree?

Comment: Your example is a bit of an anti-pattern for named returns.  Naming these return values isn't adding clarity or saving you any lines of code.  If you weren't trying to assign into that named return, you would never have perceived a problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

1 line of code won't make a huge difference but having a `tmp` variable actually sticking around for the entire function is a problem. Temporary variables should be temporary, obviously. For that, you can declare `tmp` in a new scope.

```
var s string;
{
    tmp, err := foo(in)
    s = string(tmp)
}

//tmp no longer exists here.
//Other code is not disturbed by a useless tmp variable.
```

I may be just being stupid here as I am new to Go, I learnt this trick from C, turns out it works for Go as well.